# Struggling with SqlCommands Queries Baffle me

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm struggling hard at making a testing program for my database.

My database connection works and everything I just can't seem to get the queries to work. And I have no idea on how to view the results in maybe a listbox or something.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static string Query1()
{
    List<string[]> returnvalue = new List<string[]>();

    if (DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection())
    {
        try
        {              
            DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UniqueWeapon U, Weapon W WHERE W.WeaponID = U.WeaponIDFK AND U.AllyIDFK IS NOT NULL AND W.Damage > 10 AND W.WeaponType = 'Spell';", DatabaseConnection.connect);
            cmd.Connection = DatabaseConnection.connect;

            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            dap.Fill(tbl);

            //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UniqueWeapon U, Weapon W WHERE W.WeaponID = U.WeaponIDFK AND U.AllyIDFK IS NOT NULL AND W.Damage > 10 AND W.WeaponType = 'Spell';";
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();             

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dap.Fill(tbl);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Query Failed: " + e.StackTrace + e.Message.ToString());
            return "returnvalue";
        }
        finally
        {
            DatabaseConnection.CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    return "returnvalue";
}
```

Any feedback or help would be sick!

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "I just cant seem to get the Queries to work" .. you have errors? ... wrong result ? .. no results? .. provide data samples and the expected  result

Comment: it doesnt look like you are doing anything with the results to "print them into my application" as your sock puppet account says

Comment: You are using a join syntax outdated more than 20 years ago. Did you find this on some ancient website? Use proper ANSI joins instead: `SELECT * FROM Weapon W JOIN UniqueWeapon U ON U.WeaponIDFK = W.WeaponID AND U.AllyIDFK IS NOT NULL WHERE W.Damage > 10 AND W.WeaponType = 'Spell'`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code:

1) The usage of the method DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection()

```
if (DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection()) // means it's true with Connection to db
{
    try
    {              
        DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection(); // why you open it again
       .......
```

2) you return dummy string, and already you created local DataTable filled with data but invisible outside the scope of the method

3) you fill datatable twice

4) you don't trace the results with Debug to know where is the problem

Modify your code as follows:
Read my comments in your code. I created DatabaseConnection class to test the provided code and it's working.

```
 public static DataTable Query1()
    {
       // why this variable returnvalue, you don't fill it
        List<string[]> returnvalue = new List<string[]>(); 

        //check the connection with database by using DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection() only once, and using the property Connect

        if (DatabaseConnection.connect.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection();

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable(); //use it as a return value

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UniqueWeapon U, Weapon W WHERE W.WeaponID = U.WeaponIDFK AND U.AllyIDFK IS NOT NULL AND W.Damage > 10 AND W.WeaponType = 'Spell';", DatabaseConnection.connect);

            cmd.Connection = DatabaseConnection.connect; //connect is SQlConnection

            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            //DataTable tbl = new DataTable(); //use it as a return value
            dap.Fill(tbl);
            Debug.WriteLine(tbl.Rows.Count);
            //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UniqueWeapon U, Weapon W WHERE W.WeaponID = U.WeaponIDFK AND U.AllyIDFK IS NOT NULL AND W.Damage > 10 AND W.WeaponType = 'Spell';";
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();             

            //why that code, you already filled the table using SqlDataAdapter

            //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //while (reader.Read())
            //{
            //    dap.Fill(tbl);
            //}

            // but if you want to fill datatable from Datareader use: tbl.Load(reader)
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Query Failed: " + e.StackTrace + e.Message.ToString());
            //return "returnvalue";
        }
        finally
        {
            DatabaseConnection.CloseConnection();
        }


        //return "returnvalue";
        return tbl;
    }
```